# How to render component only when data is fetched from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've had a problem with refreshing page in react app with using context api. After refreshing page in my console I see this logs:

[image]

my context fetch data from rest api but only the third time by what cause that my span is empty after end refreshing page :/

Here is my component with using data from context api.

Header/index.tsx

```
  const { currentAccount } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log("ACCOUNT: ", currentAccount);

  return (
       <span>{currentAccount?.name}</span>
  );
```

This is my applicationContext

ApplicationContext.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    checkLogin();
  }, []);

  const checkLogin = async () => {
    console.log("checkLogin");

    setLoggedIn(false);

    const token = localStorage.getItem("session");

    if (token) {
      const decode = jwt(token);
      const query = {
        id: decode["id"]
      };
      const response: Account = await axios.get("/auth/account", query);
      setCurrentAccount(response);
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setCurrentAccount(null);
      setLoggedIn(false);
    }
  }
```

Here is also my routing from App.tsx

```
        <AppContextProvider>
          {publicRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
            <Route key={i} path={path} component={component} />
          ))}
          <Main>
            {privateRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
              <Route key={i} path={path} component={component} />
            ))}
          </Main>
        </AppContextProvider>
```

can someone tell me how to render component only when data is already fetched from my rest api? All of this is doing async so I need to wait until data is coming to app

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me, personally, like to take the following approach when rendering this type of thing:

```
const RenderOnFetch = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async () => {
        await setIsLoading(true);
        const fetchedData = await fetchData();
        setData(fetchedData);
        await setIsLoading(false);
    }, []);

    return (
    <>
        {isLoading && <p>Data is being loaded..</p>}
        {!isLoading && <p>Data has been fetched..</p>}
    </>
    )

}
```

Comment: but where i should do this? in all of my components which display data?

Comment: Yes! Each component that fetches data should have one, but if you have multiple components that do that, you may create yourself a custom hook to deal with data fetching

Comment: what I meant was:

You may create a custom hook that fetches data through props and that has a loading state that you can manage.

When you have that, you may use an instance of this custom hook in each component that you need, so instead of having multiple components that handle data fetching you would have one that would be used everywhere.You need to make it as HOC as possible

Comment: This could be a good example if you are into the idea: https://github.com/esphen/fetch-hoc

Comment: hmmm thanks, but can you show an example?

Comment: I have shared a link above that you can take a look @markWanka

Comment: It complained about the "await setIsLoading" in my case with the message: "'await' has no effect on this type of expression." But just removing it works just as well for me, thanks!